# Implicit user-defined cast operator (sometimes) does not work for the const type

Tags: c++-cli

I'm attempting to make some of our IJW wrappers between our C++ and our .NET code easier to use.

The following is a test situation with our wrapper platform:

```
// NativeWrapper.h
#pragma once
template <class T>
public ref class NativeWrapper
{
public:
    // ...
    operator T* ();
    operator T& ();
    // ...
};

// Test.h
#pragma once
class Test { /* ... */ };
#pragma make_public( Test )

// TestN.h
#pragma once
#include "NativeWrapper.h"
#include "Test.h"

public ref class TestN : public NativeWrapper<Test>
{ /* ... */ };

// main.cpp
#include "TestN.h"

void f(const Test&) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    TestN^ t = gcnew TestN();
    f(t);
    return 0;
}
```

The implicit cast from TestN^ to const Test& via the user-defined operator Test&() works just fine, as I had expected.

However, when I try this in my production code, something is different. It cannot find the proper conversion. I must do the following:

```
f((Test&)t);
```

I haven't been able to identify any fundamental differences between what I'm doing in my test and what I'm doing in the main codebase. The NativeWrapper template is identical.

What types of situations might cause the compiler to fail to use a non-const conversion operator when the only acceptable type is the const reference type?

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't post code that actually demonstrates your problem.  Having to guess, you are doing something extraordinarily dangerous and managed to defeat an important compile-time check.  The t variable is a reference to a managed object that can be moved in memory when the garbage collector compacts the heap.  This is disastrous when the f() function executes, it is keeping an unmanaged reference to an object that is no longer where it used to be.  This failure mode is very nasty and impossible to debug since this occurs quite infrequently.  Never do this.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. Unfortunately I am not able to post code demonstrating my problem at this time, as I cannot figure out any distinction between the code generating my compiler error and the above working test code. When I manage to produce a good block of code for comparison, I suppose I will repost the question with better information.
The reference returned by the cast operator is actually to an object on the native heap, so I didn't think there would be risk in this. Am I wrong in that assumption?